# Sharepoint - Issues with names being displayed

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a sharepoint list that has items listed back to 2017. Each item in the list displayed usernames as last name first and first name last but now a user of that list has noticed that names are now being displayed as first name and last name. I'm not sure if this is due to a change in AD or O365, but going back to the list...

The users of the list want to know if its possible to do anything to not see both names listed as last name first, first name last OR first name last name? Or will this have to be manually handled?

I'm new at this so anything thing helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used the People field type, it will follow the `displayName` attribute sourced from Active Directory (or Azure AD if not using Active Directory). The only fix here would be to revert to LastName, FirstName.

I suspect the users who still show as LastName, FirstName do not exist in the environment any longer. Unfortunately there is no way to update those.

Comment: Thanks Trevor! I had a feeling... but appreciate your response!!